# Cordova geolocation error function called twice

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, location, ionic2

Im using geolocation plugin to know the location in my ionic2 project. there is no problem if allowed the location. But the error function called twice. Here is my code

```js
getLocation(){
  
   Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
   console.log(resp.coords.latitude);
   console.log(resp.coords.longitude);
   this.options.distance=true;
  }).catch((error) => {
  
   
   console.log('Error getting location', error);

     let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Enable Location?',
    message: 'Allow Your Location',
    buttons: [
      {
     text: 'Cancel',
     role: 'cancel',
     handler: () => {
       console.log('Cancel clicked');
     }
      },
      {
     text: 'Go to Settings',
     handler: () => {
      Diagnostic.isLocationAuthorized().then(autherized=>{
       if(!autherized){
       Diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
       }
       
      }).catch((error)=>{
       console.log(error);
      });
      
     }
      }
    ]
     });
     alert.present();
         });
  
 };
```

Thanks in advance....